# SQL : Show date when product was present in 6 months of data

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I am pretty new to sql but have a problem I can't seem to find an answer to yet.

I need to find the month where the number of months a product  in a certain segment showed up in a report is equal to 6. However, a product may not show up in sequential months, shows up multiple times a month, and some products have not beensold in 6 months yet.

I have a database with the following attributes:

```
Entry_Id    Product_Name    Sold_Date    Payment_Amount     Segment
======================================================================
112341      ABC Product    2017/12/20        10.50         Segment 1
112342      123 Product    2016/08/21        11.20         Segment 1
112343      ABC Product    2017/12/20        11.50         Segment 1
112344      123 Product    2017/08/21        11.20         Segment 1
112345      123 Product    2017/06/12        11.20         Segment 1
112346      123 Product    2016/06/21        11.20         Segment 1
112347      123 Product    2016/05/02        11.20         Segment 1
112348      123 Product    2015/04/01        11.20         Segment 1
112348      123 Product    2018/01/05        11.20         Segment 1
```

I would like to get something to the following effect

```
Product_Name      Date where N = 6    segment
=================================================
ABC Product            N/A            Segment 1 
123 Product        2018/01/05         Segment 1
```

The Day of month does not matter, just the month where the the number of months it has shown up in is equal to 6.

This is my first question and I will be as active as possible, please ask any clarifying questions.

Thank you!

Comment: Luckily, the situation has never arisen; at least, not according to the data set

Comment: Hi there, and welcome to StackOverflow. Your question is almost good. It would be much better if you showed more sample data, at least an amount that would fit your criteria (number of 6).

Comment: Your question would be further improved if you made an attempt if you can.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that I should have more data @JorgeCampos, I have amended my post.

Comment: Why is `ABC Product` in the result when it only shows up 2 times? Is the segment always the same for a product? If not, which segment should be shown in the result?

Comment: Whoops thanks @Barmar, it is because I meant 123 Product..

Comment: Do you really mean the number of months is exactly 6, or *at least* 6?

Comment: @Barmar at least 6 months

Comment: @Barmar at least 6 months, some will have shown up more, some will have shown up less

Comment: I get that. I updated my answer to work for at least 6 months.

Comment: @Barmar , I keep getting _Error 1052 column 'Product_Name' in field list is ambiguous_..

Comment: Comments about an answer should be posted below the answer, not below the question. Anyway, I fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY` and `COUNT()` to count the number of months that each product was sold in, and `HAVING` to filter the results.

```
SELECT t1.product_name, max_date, segment
FROM yourTable AS t1
JOIN (
    SELECT product_name, MAX(sold_date) AS max_date
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY product_name
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT YEAR(sold_date), MONTH(sold_date)) >= 6
) AS t2 ON t1.product_name = t2.product_name AND t1.sold_date = t2.max_date
```

The `t2` subquery finds all the products that were sold in at least 6 different months. Joining that with the table finds the row with the last date, so its `segment` column can be selected.

If you want to include the products that weren't sold in at least 6 months, with `N/A` in that column, you can move the test out of the subquery.

```
SELECT product_name, IF(month_count >= 6, max_date, "N/A") AS last_date, segment
FROM yourTable AS t1
JOIN (
    SELECT product_name, MAX(sold_date) AS max_date, COUNT(DISTINCT YEAR(sold_date), MONTH(sold_date)) as month_count
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY product_name
) AS t2 ON t1.product_name = t2.product_name AND t1.sold_date = t2.max_date
```

Comment: I keep getting a lost connection error so I think i may need to increase my timeout

Comment: Add an index on `product_name`.

Comment: @Barmer , A product_name_Index exists. Would I just replace all product_names with product_name_indx?

Comment: Yes. You can still use `product_name` in the outer `SELECT` list, just use `product_name_indx` in the subquery and `ON` condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where 6 = (select count(distinct year(t2.sold_date), month(t2.sold_date))
           from t t2
           where t2.segment = t.segment and and t2.product = t.product and
                 t2.sold_date <= t.sold_date
          );
```

Because of the `count(distinct)`, this will show all records from the 6th month.  Also, this is not particularly efficient, but it does use just standard SQL.

You can summarize this to one row per segment/product:

```
select t.segment, t.product, min(t.sold_date)
from t
where 6 = (select count(distinct year(t2.sold_date), month(t2.sold_date))
           from t t2
           where t2.segment = t.segment and and t2.product = t.product and
                 t2.sold_date <= t.sold_date
          )
group by t.segment, t.product;
```

Comment: Are you missing a closing parenthesis? count function

Comment: Didn't knew that count can take more than one parameter. Learning something new every day here !!! \o/

Comment: @JorgeCampos . . . MySQL allows that.  Why would this have a downvote?

Comment: It was not me that downvoted it. I even cheer you up for teaching me something new! I will upvote it. Forgot to do it.

Comment: @GordonLinoff im sorry that i am so new to this but when you write 't2' are you trying to append a second table? If i dont already have a second table for the output should I?

Comment: @harvey_carmichael . . . `t2` is a table alias.  It is needed because both the subquery and the outer query refer to the same table.